# IDE with rich commenting Features

Tags: ide

I notice when I'm programming I'll leave 2 types of comments, those that describe what's going on and those that warn of issues/notes to myself to investigate something further.

Is there an IDE that allows me to flag certain comments so that I can more easily review things that I set aside to be worked on later. Ideally comments like those that are in MS office/Google docs.

Example

//comment 1: Gets the value of x
function getX
return 8*y //comment 2: 8 should be a user chosen variable

I want comment 2 to be easily noticeable even if I'm somewhere else in the file.

Answer (score 1):

There are many IDEs that will keep track of comments containing the term "TODO", for example [Jetbrains IDEs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-todo.html) and [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx).

I'd try see if the IDE you use has a plugin/feature to support todo comments.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has the ability to write `//TODO "your comment here"` which will change the color of your comment to blue. Rather than the normal green color from the generic // commenting. Also when using //TODO it will show a blue mark on the right to show where the comment is in your code. [Here](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html) is some more info on some of the things you can do with eclipse. Hope this helps however this question does depend on the programming language you are using.